# How do I setup a loop that convert the dictionary into string?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-3.7

So, I do have the excel csv file. and I need to change the dictionary into string. How do I do that? The purpose of my assignment is  **It writes the contents of a database1 dictionary back to a CSV file in the same format
as it was the original input file**

Original file name is vt.csv
I know I have to set up a loop that converts the dictionary into string but I just can't figure out how. Please help.**#I have to use this format**

```
def write_vt(db, filename):
    file = open('new_vt.csv', 'w')
```

Comment: read you class notes. Didn't go to class? Too bad...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    str = f.read()
```

You don't need the csv module.